# Out of memory error trying to load a normal jpg image

Tags: android, android-drawable

I just started a test application and added one line in Activity.onCreate():

```
Drawable testDrawable = getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.test);
```

Where test.JPG is an 8M pixel picture located in drawable folder.

If I run it I received this OOM error:

Failed to allocate a 391523340 byte allocation with 13419648 free bytes and 236MB until OOM

I know JPG files are compressed so I use some tool to convert it to bmp format. After transforming the size is about 22 MB. Why android needs about 400 MB of memory which is almost 20 times the bmp size?

Comment: `391523340 Bytes` corresponds to a `9893 * 9893` image. I highly doubt there is any screen with such a high resolution.

Comment: @BobMalooga It is 2400 * 3200 image taken by an android phone. And that's exactly my question. Why it needs so much memory for such an image.

Comment: `2400 * 3200` is only (...) `30720000 Bytes`. The formula is `X * Y * 4`. By changing the factors order, the result doesn't change.

Comment: I tried moving it to drawable-xxxhdpi folder then it works. Looking at the device monitor the heap size increased by about 23 MB which is exactly the bmp size. Still not sure why it needs 400MB if I put it in drawable folder.

Comment: Because it scales it up to the desired density? drawable corresponds to the **normal** (mdpi) density, which is 160 dpi. If your device is xxxhdpi, it will scale it 4X. But 400 MB seems to exceed these (logical) calculations a bit too much.

Comment: It's nexus 6 running android 6.0.1. Did more tests with large heap enabled: comparing to not loading that drawable, put it in drawable has a 374MB heap size addition; put it in drawable-xxxhdpi has a 23MB heap size addition; put it in mdpi has a 374MB heap size addition which is the same as putting it in drawable; put it in xxhdpi has a 41MB heap size addtion; put it in xhdpi has a 93 MB heap size addition.

Comment: I just looked at here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html seems xxxhdpi has 4 times the density of mdpi. So 4 * 4 = 16 which is about 374 / 23. So I think you are right. It's because the bitmap scaling. But xxxhdpi bitmap will be 16 times larger not 4 times larger than mdpi.

Comment: ... I'm a donkey in math... ;) But yes drawable = mdpi and the `x * y * 4` is *per density*. So if you put it in a lower density than needed (in this case, in drawable = mdpi = 1X), then it's scaled up another 4 times on an xxxhdpi device.